# Automated email reminder after 1 day

Tags: c#, winforms, smtp

Hi i would like to create an email reminder 1 day after the email reminder has been sent.Example i would like to send this email on 1st January and i would like to receive an email reminder on 2nd of jan.How would i do it? Thanks in advance

```
 try
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            message.From = new MailAddress("from@mail.com");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@mail.com"));
            message.Subject = "Subject";
            message.Body = "Content";

            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.Host = "mail.com"; 
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@mail.com", "password");
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Send(message);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("err: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Sending on a certain day would do too

Comment: Use a Scheduled Task.

Answer (score 1):

With the limited amount of info you provide you'll get low quality answers. In general I'd say find a scheduler, get your e-mail script to add an item to the queue, get your scheduler to look at the queue and send reminders as required.

Comment: may i ask how do i do a scheduler is it in codes or a add on @trs

Comment: The most basic approach depends on your OS. If you are running a unix system of some sort you will probably have `cron`. On windows there is the `Task Scheduler` service.

Comment: How about Linux Kernel 2.4.22?

Comment: I would have put that in the unix bucket which is probably not right but you'll be using `cron` -- hit your favourite search engine: "How do I create a cron job?"